# Using Puppeteer with a Discord Bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, puppeteer

My friend & I have been working on a Discord bot that uses Puppeteer, a Node library that allows headless browser automation. Right now, the program logs into our school's website, and can display the grades of the user that logged in through the Discord bot. The eventual goal is to create a bot that automatically sends Discord notifications to our class's server about new assignments posted by teachers.
Here's a small sample of what the login process consists of so far:

```
await page.type('#username', username);
await page.click("#recaptcha");
await page.waitForSelector(".googleplus-login", {visible: true});
const newPagePromise = new Promise(x => browser.once('targetcreated', target => x(target.page())));
if (userAgent.includes("Headless")) {
  // Headless Browsing
  console.log("Headless Mode");
  await page.click(".googleplus-login");
  const newPage = await newPagePromise;
  await newPage.waitForSelector("#Email", {visible: true});
  await newPage.type("#Email", username);
  await newPage.click("#next");
```

So far, our best idea is to have certain people volunteer that take certain classes to run Puppeteer in the background, in order to make a "web", consisting of all the various classes everyone takes. This "web" would allow my computer to take the data from all the computers running Puppeteer every 15 minutes, and send notifications to the entire server on what classes have had new assignments posted. This solution feels bulky, and it wouldn't work for everyone.

Is there another alternative to our idea? Preferably one that only runs on one computer? I don't mind if it uses something other than Puppeteer, as long as it uses Node.

Thanks!

P.S: Our school's website does have an API, but it's only available to school IT administrators. Therefore, we have to go through the login process with Puppeteer, which takes a little bit.